# My code is not reading all emails from inbox

Tags: python, outlook

I am reading all emails from my inbox through python code as below:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
for msg in messages :`enter code here`
    print(msg.Subject)
```

But it is skipping few emails in between the mails. Please help.

Comment: Are the missing emails are from Inbox folder? It won't give you emails from sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which subjects are printed can be different from the view in Outlook. The sorting filter in the view can be retrieved by using the `View` object from the Outlook object model.

To obtain a `View` object for the view of the current `Explorer`, use `Explorer.CurrentView` instead of the `CurrentView` property of the current `Folder` object returned by `Explorer.CurrentFolder`.

The `View` object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.

- The table view type (olTableView) allows you to view data in a simple field-based table.
- The Calendar view type (olCalendarView) allows you to view data in a calendar format.
- The card view type (olCardView) allows you to view data in a series of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item and can be sorted.
- The icon view type (olIconView) allows you to view data as icons, similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
- The timeline view type (olTimelineView) allows you to view data as it is received in a customizable linear time line.

Views are defined and customized using the `View` object's [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.xml) property. The `XML` property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.